# App not connected when database changed from one host to another

Tags: database, migration, cpanel

I had moved my website and databases to another hosting service provider. However, my app doesn't seem to connect even after entering the new configuration details. Any tips what I need to look out for. Mine is a simple quiz app where the questions sit in a database and the app pulls out the categories and questions. The php files are on my new server. Also the cpanel to edit the questions in the database does not work. Instead the following code shows up on the index page. Thank you.

query("SELECT * FROM iqm_admin WHERE name ='$login' and pass = sha1('$pass') "); if (!$sl) echo 'Login failed'; if ($sl->num_rows>0) $_SESSION['authorization_admin_iqm'] = $login; else{ ?>
Incorrect password or login

back...

I am trying to connect the app to the database and also to access the cpanel to edit questions in the database.

Thanks.